# Find server IP in local network with known port in python socket

Tags: python, sockets, ip, port

I'm designing a network game and I specified a port for my game. How can I program the client side to find the ip of local servers with my specified port number. What I mean is how can I find ip of server by knowing opened port?

Comment: Broadcast is the best option , your client should send a broadcast packet to find the server. Otherwise the client must be told the IP of the server manually.

Comment: @thecreator232 Can you explain a little more? Or show me some code!